# How to configure emacs to auto-indent with fixed spaces instead of align to the open parenthesis?

Tags: emacs, indentation

For example, I would like this style of indention:

```
int expectedIndent(int param1,
    int param2){}
```

instead of this style:

```
int currentIndent(int param1,
                  int param2){}
```

Thanks in advance,
Utoah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(c-set-offset 'arglist-intro '+)
(c-set-offset 'arglist-cont-nonempty '+)
(c-set-offset 'arglist-close '+)
```

More details: http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/html-manual/Paren-List-Symbols.html#Paren-List-Symbols

Comment: And what would be the correspoding modeline?, I tried with
// Local variables:
// c-basic-offset: 4 
// tab-width: 4                                                                 
// indent-tabs-mode: t                                                          
// truncate-lines: t                                                            
// c-set-offset: 'arglist-intro '+ 
// c-set-offset: 'arglist-cont-nonempty '+ 
// c-set-offset: 'arglist-close '+
and no luck.